# Backbone.js model validate method fails to fire

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to understand how Backbone.js model validation works, but I'm seeing some odd inconsistencies. In one place in my app, the `validate` method is getting called as expected. In another place, however, Backbone.js seems to be passing in a `{ silent: true }` object to the validator, even though I don't want it to.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/J3uuH/11/) that illustrates the issue. The `validate` method should be called When the Copy buttons are clicked or the values change, but when I step through the code it's clear that the `_validate` function is being passed the `{ silent: true }` option.

What am I missing?

Update: Figured out what was going on here. I created this jsFiddle originally to replicate an issue I was having that was actually the opposite of this question--I was trying to add an empty model to a collection and validation was firing and preventing me from doing so. When I made the Fiddle, though, it worked as I wanted my app to work. Validation wasn't firing when an empty model was added. I couldn't figure out the difference.

Turns out I was using Backbone.js 0.9.0 in my application and version 0.9.1 in my jsFiddle. Jeremy made changes to validation in 0.9.1 to make it work the way I wanted it to work in my app (see [this issue](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/917) on GitHub). Mystery solved.

Comment: So... it should validate whenever a new item is generated and nothing is being set to it?

Comment: Yeah. I know it doesn't make much sense in this example; it's a simplified scenario. In the part of my app that's working, `validate` gets called whenever a new model is added to the collection, even if all of its properties are set to `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone specifically does not call `_validate` when you're making a new model.

Jeremy suggests that you do:

```
var mymodel = new MyModel();
mymodel.set({params});
```

Here's our exchange on github: [can't override silent:true](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1049)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Backbone docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate), it seems you have to either call set or save on the model in order for validate to trigger.

I updated the jsfiddle so that `set` is called, and the now the validation function gets triggered:

http://jsfiddle.net/J3uuH/12/